# See who viewed a particular record going back 6 years

Tags: event-monitoring

Our org is subject to certain compliance rules that means we have to be able to answer who viewed a given record and when, going back up to 6 years.

The org includes a Shield Event Monitoring feature license.

Real-time event monitoring keeps URI events for only [6 months](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/real_time_event_monitoring_storage.htm); same issue for the Event Monitoring Analytics App ([30 days](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/event_monitoring/event_monitoring_intro)), thus there's no OOTB solution here that I'm aware of.

How do we solve this with the least amount of work and cost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution we used (and there may be others so other answers are welcome!) was the [Salesforce Collector for SumoLogic](https://help.sumologic.com/07Sumo-Logic-Apps/18SAAS_and_Cloud_Apps/Salesforce/01Collect-Logs-for-Salesforce) (that happens to be our enterprise logging tool). The Sumologic Salesforce app requires no install in Salesforce and is a no cost add-on for SumoLogic licensees. The only SFDC config is an integration user + connected app that the collector uses to query the EventLog objects on a regular basis.

And the sumologic query to see who accessed a given Case record can be done using:

```
_sourceCategory=production/sfdc
| json auto keys "EVENT_TYPE", "URI_ID_DERIVED" as eventtype, uriidderived
| where eventtype = "URI"
| where uriidderived = "500xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

where `500xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` is the Id of a case of interest

generates Log entries that would look like:

```
{"EVENT_TYPE": "URI", 
 "TIMESTAMP": "20210324135127.148", 
 "REQUEST_ID": "4axAZm445f_mjikCad-BX-", 
 "ORGANIZATION_ID": "00D36000000xxxx", 
 "USER_ID": "005xxxxxxxx", 
 "RUN_TIME": "606", 
 "CPU_TIME": "339", 
 "URI": "/5001Q00001ArxGL", 
 "SESSION_KEY": "CBsGJzuf4owDIjm0", 
 "LOGIN_KEY": "dxw6Wt70S46GgCqv", 
 "REQUEST_STATUS": "S", 
 "DB_TOTAL_TIME": "266670746", 
 "DB_BLOCKS": "2986", 
 "DB_CPU_TIME": "120", 
 "REFERRER_URI": "", 
 "TIMESTAMP_DERIVED": "2021-03-24T13:51:27.148Z", 
 "USER_ID_DERIVED": "005xxxxxxxxxxxx", 
 "CLIENT_IP": "99.120.xxx.xxx", 
 "URI_ID_DERIVED": "5001Q00001ArxGLQAZ", 
 "USER_ID_DERIVED_LOOKUP": "fred.fubar@mycompany.com"}
```

So you can see that Fred viewed the Case at `2021-03-24T13:51:27.148Z`

The volume of SFDC event logs collected by SumoLogic was a small fraction of the total logs from all other apps so storage costs were lost in the noise.  YMMV.

*Obviously, the lookback can only go back as far as when you first install the SumoLogic Collector*